# Debug core file with LLDB without executable, but with debug symbols file

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, lldb, coredump

I have a core dump file that needs to be debugged. But the only file that I have for crashed program is a debug symbols file

Exec and debug file were generated with:

```
$ gcc -g -O0 -o <exec> main.c
$ objcopy --only-keep-debug <exec> <exec>.dbg
$ strip --strip-debug --strip-unneeded <exec>
```

When I'm running lldb with my core file as a target and trying to add symbols file, lldb gives me an error:

```
$ lldb -c <core-file>
(lldb) target symbols add <exec>.dbg
error: symbol file '<exec>.dbg' does not match any existing module
```

Then, I tried to add module with my .dbg file and only then add it as symfile. No errors this time, but still no symbols was added -- `bt` gives me only 1 frame in 1 thread, and I can't see any code in `gui` mode

```
$ lldb -c <core-file>
(lldb) target modules add <exec>.dbg
(lldb) target symbols add <exec>.dbg
```

#### My questions are:

Firstly, I've barely found any information about what is lldb "module"

Secondly, I don't understand why lldb needs any information besides my core and debug files. Core file has snapshot of the memory, and debug file has all the symbols that can help parse core file contents to "human-readable" form.

Lastly, is it even possible to debug core file with symbols, but without executable? If it isn't in lldb, maybe there is a way in gdb or other debbuger?
Or, maybe I generated debug file incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> maybe there is a way in gdb or other debbuger?

This worked for me:

```
gdb -q a.dbg core
Reading symbols from a.dbg...

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.

Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50        return ret;

(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007fcad7676797 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x0000000000203af9 in foo () at main.c:5
#3  0x00007ffe54685830 in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000000203b14 in main () at main.c:10
```

**Update:**
Here are the exact steps I took:

```
// t.c
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo() {
  abort();
}

int main()
{
  return foo();
}
```

```
// t.sh
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -c unlimited
gcc -g t.c &&
objcopy --only-keep-debug a.out a.dbg &&
strip --strip-debug --strip-unneeded a.out

./a.out
rm -f a.out

gdb -q a.dbg core
```

Note: even though there is a somewhat reasonable stack, it is *not* correct: `frame#3` does not really exist.

In general, note that you are *doing it wrong* -- the debugger *does* need access to the code, not just debug symbols to unwind the stack (though I am not sure of the exact details of why that is).

You should *either* preserve the original (unstripped) `a.out`, *or* preserve *both* the stripped `a.out` *and* `a.dbg`.

Comment: Can you show all your steps please, like, all of them, including cp'ing dumps and etc.

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer, but it would be really helpful if someone could describe why does gdb or lldb still need executable with debug symbols

Comment: It looks like you are on some sort of Linux system?  If that's the case, remember that the core file is a dump of the memory image of the process when it crashed.  However, the ELF file format allows for "no load" sections in a binary, and anything that's not needed by the runtime is not loaded to save memory (and thus is not in the core file).  That very well might include some non-debug-only symbol information that the debugger uses but the runtime does not.  But that's just a guess.